# How to navigate to other page after a pop up confirmation ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a login page in ionic for mobile app where after the user enter some ID and password, it will navigate to another page. I try to use the state.go and location.path but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
    angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic','ui.router'])
    .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.data ={};
    $scope.submitData = function(){

    if($scope.data.email && $scope.data.password){
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Login Succesful",
            template: "Welcome Back "
        });
        $state.go('stateHome');
    }else{

        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Login Failed",
            template: "Please check your credentials"
        });
    }
    }
    })
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('stateHome', {
        url: '/Home',
        views: {
        'Home' :{
        templateUrl : "templates/Home.html",
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'

        }
        }
    });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Setting');


    })
```

My app.js contain :

```
    angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    });
    })
```

any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your files as follows. It should work. I can elaborate if you find it confusing.

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider

    .state('stateHome', {
        url: '/Home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/Home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Setting');
})
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, $location) {

    $scope.data ={};
    $scope.submitData = function(){

    $scope.goToHomePage = function () {
        $location.path("/Home");
    };

      if($scope.data.email && $scope.data.password){
         var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Login Succesful",
            template: "Welcome Back "
         });    
         alertPopup.then(function(res) {
            if(res) {
               $scope.goToHomePage();
             } else {
               console.log('Do something else');
             }
          });

      }else{

           var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: "Login Failed",
              template: "Please check your credentials"
          });
        }
      }
   })
```

Comment: I have try your suggestion, but still, after i go to the login page and put email and password, the pop up 'login successful' is executed but the page still in the login page instead of Home page, any idea the part I might be missing?

Comment: I think I see your issue. What does your directory structure look like? Do you have an app.js? And if so, can you post it? I can see that this line onwards ->  `app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)` looks out of place, unless you just pasted them it underneath your controller for this post.

Comment: My directory structure look like the common one which are the appname and then inside got hooks plugins scss www ,inside www is js, img, lib, template and etc. Basically it's the exact thing we get when we downloading it using CLI from creator ionic. I do have an app.js.

Comment: So in your code above, is `angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic','ui.router'])` to halfway down your code where you have `})` in it's own controller module? And is the rest (`app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {` onwards) in your `app.js`?

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my answer now to show you how it should look.